# Prove that $-x^2 \leq x^n \leq x^2$ for $-1<x<1, n\in \mathbb N, n \geq3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that $-x^2 \leq x^n \leq x^2$ for $-1<x<1, n\in \mathbb N, n \geq3$

I have no idea how to do this, I don't even know how to begin. Please help!

Comment: Use Induction. ${}$

Comment: Think about what happens to a number between zero and one when you raise it to higher and higher powers?

Comment: I would suggest to either relax the conditions to $-1\leq x\leq 1$ or refine the statement to $-x^2<x^n<x^2$. There is no need to mix strict equalities and non-strict ones here.

Comment: @String I have to derive this inequality then use it to prove that $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^n=0$ via Squeeze Theorem. So I guess I will change it to non-strict equalities :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You have to prove $|x^n|\leq x^2$ for $|x|<1$. You know that for any $a>0$ and $0<b<1$, $ab<a$. Then, for $n=3$, we have that
$$
|x^3|=x^2\cdot |x|.
$$
Now set $b=|x|$, $a=x^2$, and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

If $x<1$ is positive we have
$$
x^2>\underbrace{x\cdot x^2}_{x^3}>\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot x^2}_{x^4}>...
$$
The negative bound is only relevant when $n$ is odd and $x$ is negative.